# What is the right RegEx pattern to match this case?

Tags: json, regex

I am trying, and failing miserably, to write regex that will match all of the following lines that have integers in em. I'll add comments to indicate which ones should match.

```
"modelstub": "some-123908", // No match
"modelstub": "00432", // No match
"modelstub": "1607", // No match
"modelstub": 16-02, // No Match 
"modelstub": 1605, // Match!
"modelstub": 1604, // Match!
"modelstub": 1603, // Match!
"modelstub": "1-602", // No match
```

Please forgive me for I am using ColdFusion. Trust me no one hates it more than me.

But here's what I tried: `("modelstub":+)[0-9]+`

Full code reference:

```
<cfset output = REReplace(output, '("modelstub":+)[0-9]+', '"modelstub": "$1"', "ALL")>
```

Comment: Could you also add what you have tried? So you mean a match like https://regex101.com/r/LDysZs/1

Comment: It is not clear what the rules are. 16-02 also "has integers in them", and it is not clear what the condition is on the left side. Should it be a quoted string, should there be a colon, should there be a space, ... etc.

Comment: Maybe you look for `\"[^"]*\"\s*:\s*\d+,` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern that you use, you are repeating the `:` 1 or more times using `:+` and there is a space missing between the colon and the double quote.

You could update your pattern to `("modelstub":) [0-9]+$` and you will then have a capturing group.

To get the match only without the group, if there is a comma at the end of the string, you could use:

```
"modelstub": \d+,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDysZs/1/)

If here is no comma, you might use:

```
"modelstub": \d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDysZs/2)

Answer (score 1):

if there's a comma at the end of each line then the solution from @Thefourthbird will work.  if not then try this: `"modelstub": \d+$`